# Ритины или Ритыны друзья?

Tags: орфография

Почему правильно писать Ритины, а не Ритыны друзья?

Comment: И причем тут это? Вопрос о выборе суффикса. Мама - мамин, Лена-Ленин, Рита-Ритин. Правда, после Ц принято писать ЫН -Птицын.

Comment: Ритины же не производится от слова "Риты", а от слова "Рита" где "ы" нет.

Comment: ???
А **И** есть?

Comment: А что вы называете существительным и его окончанием? O_o

Comment: Но в других притяжательных прилагательных вроде тоже -ин, откуда вообще идея писать -ын?

Comment: Соглашусь с @DocentI. Так и не понял, откуда взяли -ын.

Comment: С утреждением насчет прилагательный я тожк соглашусь. А вот насчет "слова Рита, где нет Ы" было не очень понятно.  
Попробую пояснить, откуда могла взяться идея насчет Ы, она кстати не такая уж редкая, сталкивался. 
1. Общие особенности говора какой-то группы или местности. Об этом писал. Возможно, белорусский - не самый удачный пример, там и Р всегда твердое (т.е. получилось бы [рытын]/[Рыц'ин] - с мягким ц), но смысл, надеюсь, понятен.  
2. В имени "Рита" Т твердый. Таких имен немного: Света, Надежда, Рит - ну еще несолько, механизм смягчения перед -ин- до автоматизма не доведен.

Comment: А, я, кажется, понял. Вы говорите о том, что нельзя строго требовать перенесения фонетико одного слова на другое. Если так, то я отчасти согласен. Только тут речь идёт не о об окончании _существительнного_ слова и _суффиксе_ прилагательного а всего лишь о смягчении конечного _корневого_ согласного.

Comment: Мы не так часто видим притяжательные прилагательные написанными. А в устной речи, действительно, часто звучит "РитЫн". Видно,  и написали так же. Получили ошибку. А интересно, произношение именно мягкого конечного основы где-нибудь оговаривается?

Comment: Вова - Вовины. Второе в "у Вовы" твердее некуда)
Будем говорить Вовыны??

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы!  Я знаю, что правильно РитИна, но сотрудница потребовала аргументировать )))

Comment: Честно говоря, у меня язык не поворачивается сказать "Ритыны". Только путем автонасилия. Откуда и недоумение.

Answer (score 5):

В данном случае уже потому, что так произносится по литературной норме.
Произношение "РитЫны" норме не соответствует, оно обычно свойственно носителям языков, в которых нет разделения согласных на твердые-мягкие, и жителям тех мест, где сильно влияние таких языков. Такое возможно, например, в Белоруссии, в белорусском нет мягкого Т.  
Но нормативно, повторюсь, именно "Ритины".